# (int)false; in php why would it be?

Tags: php, codeigniter, boolean, logic

I am reviewing a partner php code and is like:

```
function query_db($form)
{
   $result = (int)false;    
   try{
    $sqlQuery = " SELECT id_user, id_access, name, email, status FROM users ";
    $sqlQuery .= " WHERE id_access> 0 ";
    if($form->get("limit")){
       $sqlQuery .= " LIMIT ".$form->get("start")." , ".$form->get("registry");
    }           
        $query = $this->db->query($sqlQuery);
    return $query;
   } catch (Exception $e) { 
    $result = (int)false;
   }
    return $result;
}
```

So at the very begining he uses `$result = (int)false;`

I was investigating this instruction and found:

> A string is converted to false only if it is empty or if it contains
>   the single character
>   0. If it contains any other data—even multiple zeros—it is converted to true.
>
> When converted to a number or a string, a Boolean becomes 1 if it is
>   true, and 0 otherwise.

So back to the question:

```
echo 0 + 1; // 1
echo false + 1; // 1
echo 0  > -1; // true
echo false  > -1; // false
echo (int)false > -1; // true
```

So why in the world he casts it instead of using  `$result = 0;` I mean, I do not understand, maybe it has a deeper meaning and I am not seing this.

Thats why I ask your opinion.

Comment: He probably couldn't remember of 0 was false or -1... so he let the language do it for him.

Comment: but isn't a standar to use 0 as false and 1 as true, -1 is error, or maybe I am wrong

Comment: yes, you are wrong, the boolean just has 2 values: FALSE (0) / TRUE (not 0). -1 or others are INTEGER values man. To know what exactly returned from a function, you should read the document carefully instead of guessing.

Comment: @cMinor I'm not saying what he's doing is right I'm just trying to guess at what would compel someone to do something so non-sensical

Comment: well I meant when not using boolean, but integers, (0 false), (1 true), (-1 error), I understand boolean can only be true or false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to "why would it be" is the simple answer: type coercion.

In your quote, you touched upon the answer:

> When converted to a number or a string, a Boolean becomes 1 if it is true, and 0 otherwise.

Through type coercion, the `(int)false` converts the value to `0`. If you were to have `(int)!false`, it would be `1`.

The answer to "why would your friend use this", that's something you'll have to ask him =P. There is no benefit to doing this in this code-block and could be replaced with `$result = 0` with zero effect on the outcome.

In response to a comment, `0` is *typically* `false` and `1` is `true`. When referring to success and error codes, however, it is highly dependent on the system you're interacting with. For instance, in `bash`, `0` is a "successful" exit code and `1` would mean an error occurred.

*Not answer related*:
In your exact code-block, you can actually remove the `$result` variable entirely since the code only-ever uses it to return `0` if the query failed; instead, you can just have `return 0;` at the end - or `return false;` if you'd prefer dealing directly with boolean values.

Comment: Yes I was about to ask him, but Nothing kind came to my mind... so instead of judging first I must inform my self, but that was very strange to see on someone code...

Comment: @cMinor Most of the time things like this were caused by "writing while planning"; he may have been coming up with a plan to create constant variables for placeholders, such as `ERROR` or `SUCCESS` and forgot to write them / put them in place. Or, who knows, maybe just a goof on his end =P

Answer (score 4):

The only reason I can see for casting `false` as an `int` would be for the identical [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Take the below example for instance:

```
<?php
$x = false;
$y = (int)false;

if($x===false){ // validates
    echo 'Test x.1<br>';
}

if($x===FALSE){ // validates
    echo 'Test x.2<br>';
}

if($x===0){ // skips
    echo 'Test x.3<br>';
}

if($x==0){ // validates
    echo 'Test x.4<br>';
}

if(!$x){ // validates
    echo 'Test x.5<br>';
}

if(empty($x)){ // validates
    echo 'Test x.6<br>';
}

if($y===false){ // skips
    echo 'Test y.1<br>';
}

if($y===FALSE){ // skips
    echo 'Test y.2<br>';
}

if($y===0){ // validates
    echo 'Test y.3<br>';
}

if($y==0){ // validates
    echo 'Test y.4<br>';
}

if(!$y){ // validates
    echo 'Test y.5<br>';
}

if(empty($y)){ // validates
    echo 'Test y.6<br>';
}
```